# Hilt create single dependency with multiple scopes

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

Is there a way that I can have a dependency that I need to use in a service and activity created with different scopes in different modules so that I can Inject it in both the service and activity.

Answer (score -2):

You can use @Singleton for this purpose.

Comment: Please try to add more information to your answer. It always helps, if you add example code and also explain what it does / how it works.

Comment: Please try to use @Singleton annotation to inject your dependency I have attached an example.
If you want to use this Network class in both service and activity so you Annotate it with @Singleton.

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideNetworkConnectivity(@ApplicationContext context: Context): NetworkConnectivity {
        return Network(context)
    }
```
Please try this and let me know if It's helpful for you.
Thanks